# PHP cookie lost after closing browser

Tags: php, cookies

When I open my website on localhost on chrome or other browser it set cookie until I close my browser. When I close my Chrome or other browser it delete my cookie even I have specified expiry time also. But it not lost on fire-fox, in fire-fox cookie is working properly even after closing browser. Why chrome and other browser delete my cookie after closing browser.

the code I have used :

```
setcookie( "CookieName", "Cookievalue", time() + 3600, "/");
```

Comment: Your cookie expires in 3600 sec

Answer (score 0):

Hello and  Welcome Lucky Jaiswal, Please first off check whether chrome clears all cookies on exit. You can do this by going to ***settings*** then to ***privacy and security*** and then click on ***cookies and site data***, there will be a toggle button saying ***clear all cookies and site data on exit*** please check if it is *toggled on* if yes please *toggle it off* and try your code again. If the problem still persists I shall try to give you another solution.

(Edit_2) Try this:

```
<?php 

    if ( isset($_COOKIE['test']) ) {

        echo 'Cookie exists';

    } else {

        echo 'Cookie not found';

    }

    if (isset($_POST['login'])) {

        if ( $_POST['name'] /* Add your extra conditions for example $_POST['name'] && $_POST['email'] && $_POST['password'] something like that*/ ) {

            print_r($_POST);
        
            session_start(); 

            ob_start();
        
            $name = $_POST['name'] ?? '';
        
            $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "trial") ;
        
            $query = "SELECT * FROM `trialtable` WHERE `name` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $name)."'";
        
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("Error 3");
        
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        
            if ($name == $row['name']) {
            
                setcookie("test", '"'.$row['id'].'"', time() + 3600, "/");
        
            } 
        
            mysqli_close($conn);

        }

    }

?>
```

P.S: Tested in Chrome, Microsoft Edge and Firefox!

Comment: No that toggle button is already off. It didn't helpfull for me  but thanks for answering.

Comment: Hmm... could you show me the script when the `COOKIE` is being set, thanks.

Comment: <?php
    if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
        session_start();
        ob_start();
        
        $name = $_POST['inp'];
        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "trial") ;
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `trialtable` WHERE name = '$name' ";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("Error 3");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        if ($name == $row['name']) {
            //set cookie
            setcookie("CookieName", "Cookievalue", time() + 3600, "/");
            }
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>

Comment: @LuckyJaiswal Check my above answer's edit.

Comment: Also it is a best practice to escape anything before saving it to a database as that can prevent [mySQL Injections](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwit3_aS0-P3AhVW7HMBHRFqCLAQFnoECAkQAw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tizag.com%2FmysqlTutorial%2Fmysql-php-sql-injection.php&usg=AOvVaw2MdKTHhmC6-UWMfNCBbsH2)

Comment: The code which you gave me it work on Brave, fire-fox, opera browsers but not on chrome and micro soft edge browsers. Can solve this mystery 

Comment: **To check cookies in Chrome:**

_Right-click and click on Inspect to open the developer console._
                                                                                                                     _Go to the Applications tab on the console._
                                                                                                                    _Expand the Cookies dropdown under the Storage section. Under Cookies, select the website to see the cookie details._

Comment: 2022-05-16T12:59:04.5775Z is showing in expires/max-age section

Comment: Edit 2 added please check the edit and let me know @Lucky Jaiswal. If my answer has been helpful I would appreciate if you could make my answer the solution, Ciao.

Comment: @LuckyJaiswal Note if the expiry time is omittedthen the cookie will be deleted on the closing of the browser...